# Preparing your Software to Sell/Market

Tags: windows, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, code-signing, product-key

I know this is a broad question.  You will understand why in just a moment. (Because I’m bouncing around searching for this issue, then stop and look up this issue, when all of these are Related/Can be combined).

I have 20+ years experience developing massive IN-HOUSE databases, utilities, etc. When Clients were involved we went ON SITE and installed software on the systems. Last year I decided to branch out and develop a software package outside the realm of Databases of my own. I am now ready to put on the market.  HERE is WHERE I LACK experience.

QUESTION:  How do you prepare the software to sell (If one of you have; Addressed all these issues here, have a blog or book, that would be helpful). To address the following issues;

PREPARING SOFTWARE TO SELL

1. Obtaining Code Signature and How to implement.
2. After Customer downloads;

   - Write your own Product Key/Activation Feature (Method/Difficulties)
   - Implement, Purchase Library for product Key/Activation
   - Using a Service for Product Key/Activation
3. Coding for In app Purchases (Methods/Difficulties)
4. Windows Store Software would eliminate some of this - so how
   long/difficult to setup(Difficulties). How well do they actually do?

Am I overlooking something (Windows platform). WHY, YOU MAY ASK; Because I looked up one thing; Setup website (some coding) for software download, saw Service provides it's own download - now removing code. I Need YOUR EXPERIENCED advice (Or 1-STOP that address these issues together).

Comment: Is your application UWP app or desktop app ? If your app is one of them,how about publish your application to the Microsoft store? Microsoft Store will automatically help you maintain the app's certificate and manage your in app purchase.

Comment: @DasiyTian - it is a Desktop app. I did look at the bridge (and truthfully I may consider UWP at a future date).  The problem is making the decision and I have questions such as; How complicated is this (bridge)? Is this a MAJOR learning curve (Windows Store)? I just hate going forward - and then finding at this is not a good solution (been there done that). NOT EVEN MS Office is on the store - let alone any major pro software. So I wonder is it even viable option. Do you have experience at this?

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted out the whole process of uploading desktop app to Store for you. It seems complicated, but it is actually some simple steps.First of all,
an illustration of Desktop Bridge for you(just package your project,not complicated).

[image]

To publish a Desktop app in the Store, there are some steps you need to figure out.

1.You need a developer account to publish your app to the Store, please refer to [Opening a developer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account#the-account-signup-process)

2.[Reserve an app name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-your-app-by-reserving-a-name#create-your-app-by-reserving-a-new-name) in your [Windows Dev Center dashboard](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/pcv/dashboard/overview)

3.Package your application

1).[Package your project with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net#create-a-package)(can refer to the small video at the buttom of the document)

2).[Package a desktop application manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion)

4.Start your App submission in Dev center dashboard

(1)[Set app pricing and availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability)

(2)[Enter app properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/enter-app-properties)

(3)Fill the [age rating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/age-ratings) questionnaire

(4)[Upload app packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/upload-app-packages), For your desktop bridge app, when you upload the package, there will be a note for you,do not worry,you just need to fill the information in the submission page(I will point it in the step 6),the note is as the picture shown:[image]

(5)[Create app Store listings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-app-store-listings)

(6)[Manage submission options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-submission-options), please fill the requirement information for the `restricted capabilities`
[image]
5.You could submit app to the Store

Comment: @DasiTian MSFT - I am very impressed - When I looked some of this up - sites sent me back in forth to page to page. I continued to look at the conventional means (Code Sig./Standard Download/Activation etc.).  I will look into this today.  One Final Question - a rough est time through all the steps (any approval wait times etc)?  For example to Time Marketing Ads (Social Media ads) with Launch Time on the store.

Comment: @AdrianE  Follow the steps,when you successfully click **Submit to Store**, you will experience a few hours.After your submission passes certification, it can take up to 24 hours for customers to see the app's listing for a new submission.[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process]

Comment: Thank you @DasiyTian - This may end up being the option. I've been weighing - final choices.  What I gain and what I loose.